# well order in $M_1 \times M_2$

Tags: order-theory

If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are well ordered then $ M = M_1 \times M_2$ is well ordered too.

with the orders
$$ (a_1,b_1) \leq (a_2,b_2) \ iff \ b_1 \leq b_2 \ in  \ M_2  \ and \ a_1 \leq a_2 \ in  \ M_1 \ ,\  b_1=b_2$$

I prove that this is a total order, I prove trichotomy, transitive, but how can I prove that there existe a first element in  M.

I tried this by contradiction if $(a_0,b_0) \in M$ is first element but I don't know how continue this idea.

Someone can help me please. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: To show that $M$ is well-ordered you need to show that **any** non-empty subset has a least element, not just $M$ itself.

Comment: Could you clarify the definition of the order in the product, please? Specifically, what is the role of that $b_1 = b_2$ at the end of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "and" in your definition should be "or", in which case it works.  Let $a_0$ be the first element in $M_1$ and $b_0$ be the first element in $M_2$.  You are guaranteed they exist because $M_1,M_2$ are well ordered.  Then $(a_0,b_0)$ is the first element.  You can use your definition to show it is less than ore equal to any element of $M$.  For a well order every subset of $M$ must have a least element, but you take any collection, take the elements with the smallest second items, and take the one of those that has the smallest first item.

Comment: yea  I have  that but I don't know how to relate with the order in $M$

Comment: You use your definition.  Given a point $(a,b)$ you always have $(a_0,b_0) \le (a,b)$ because you have both $a_0 \le a, b_0 \le b$

Comment: but what happen if b_0=b ?

Comment: But shouldn't a well-ordered set be also totally ordered? (See the comment of Rob Arthan above.) If both $M_1$ and $M_2$ have more than one element, and $a_0 < a_1 \in M_1$ and $b_0 < b_1 \in M_2$, what is the first element of the set $\{ (a_0, b_1), (a_1, b_0) \}$?

Comment: @amrsa:  yes.  I took the definition of the order to be a bit poorly written and be lexicographic order starting with the second element.  More correctly it would be $(a_1,b_1) \lt (a_2,b_2) if either $b_1 \lt b_2 or ($b_1=b_2$ and $a_1 \lt a_2$)  This is a total order and a well order as long as the underlying orders are well orders.

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood the definition of the order (I asked for some clarification to the question). It turns out to be a total order. I think it is wrongly stated in the definition: it should be *or* where it is *and*, but you were able to parse it correctly perhaps without even noticing the mistake. Great!